# Trying to create kafka topics with KafkaAdmin.NewTopics, but KafkaListener manages to create a topic before it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to replicate production topic configuration in my local environments. But I have this Kafka listener that manages to start before the [NewTopics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.0-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaAdmin.NewTopics.html) bean so only a few of my topics are being created with the correct configurations, and the listener topics are created with defaults. How can I resolve this?

I am running my kafka broker from a docker-compose

My local bean is using `@ConditionalOnProperty` that checks whether kafka broker urls is a localhost url, I cannot modify the service class where the listener is being created in.

I have looked into `@DependsOn` but I don't think that will solve my problem without modifying the service class.

I have tried using the new [KafkaAdmin.createOrModifyTopics()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaAdmin.html#createOrModifyTopics(org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic...)) from `spring-kafka:2.7` but that does not update the topic configuration if a topic has been created, and from what it looks like it can only update partitions of a topic

Comment: I couldn't figure it out and at the moment it seems impossible, instead I have created a shell script that registers topics with the configurations I need via zookeeper that executes via docker-compose `command:` under the kafka service/container. At the end of the shell script I run `/etc/confluent/docker/run` to start the kafka container, otherwise Kafka container would not start

Comment: I couldn't edit the previous comment, however this might be helpful for those struggling with a similar problem [script example](https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/5.1.1-post/microservices-orders/docker-compose.yml#L182-L215) I did it differently where my script is executed in a background with the use of bash `$` and sleeps for some time until the kafka container manages to initialize.